# sonar integration with jenkins file for .net repos

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I am looking to integrate the my dotnet repo with enterprise level sonar. I want to integrate the sonar in the jenkins pipeline and add all the token in the jenkins credential  manager. Can someone guide me how to do it.

As of now my jenkins is using scripted pipeline script and has 3 stages..

- code checkout
- buiding .net project using some powershell commands
- pushing to artifactory.

I want to include an new stage related to sonar but not sure what steps we need to write under it for .net projects

Comment: I would assume you would want to fail a stage and not publish if Code Quality Gate criteria were not met. Therefore add a stage (Code-Scan) after build (and after test if code coverage wanted), before push to Artifactory. Jenkins pipeline documentation for [SQ plugin usage](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/sonar/)

Comment: @IanW Yes I want that but the goal shown in the link is corresponding to maven. I want to know for .net

Comment: @IanW I m unable to find the sonar stage implementation using jenkins scripted pipeline for ms dotnet repos.

Comment: Now that the Sonar site is back on-line, have your reviewed: [SonarScanner for .NET](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/) ? Maybe you need to show what you have and what you are missing from your pipeline in your question. The is the official [generic sonar-scanner CLI](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/) documentation.